# How can a string be added to React JSX div id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, frontend, jsx

I would like to change id of a div in jsx like so :-

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id="alphabet_{element}">
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```

But this results in

```
<div id="alphabet_{element}">
    Some
</div>
```

How can I get the actual value of {element} in my div id?

Comment: `id={'alphabet_' + element}`

Comment: you can just use template strings here actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id={`alphabet_${element}`}>
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Template literals to concat variable with strings.

```
id={`alphabet_${element}`}
```

for diff methods refer -> [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score -3):

You are assigning wrong

Try changing this

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id="alphabet_{element}"> ---> change to <div id={`alphabet_${element}`}> or <div id={"alphabet_"+element}>
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```

Comment: This wouldn't help as it doesn't provide any improvement over the initial question, try using template literals or string concatenation to improve your answer.

Comment: there's no difference between the left and right portions besides the arrows. `<div id="alphabet_{element}"> ---> change to <div id="alphabet_{element}">`